# Cumulative histogram plot from dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

The goal is to create a plot like this
[image]

Dummy df:

```
columns = ['number_of_words', 'occurrences']
data = [[1, 2312252],
       [2,1000000],
       [3,800000],
        [4, 400000],
        [5, 100000],
        [6, 70000],
        [7, 40000],
        [8, 10000],
        [9, 4000],
        [10, 50]]
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
```

The y axis represents the occurrences and the x axis the number of words column from the dummy_df.

The x axis should be cumulative such that it stacks the values on top of each other.

Example: With `number_of_words` = 1 we have around 2.3 m occurrences. With `number_of_words` = 2 we have around 1m `occurrences`, thus it should plot 2.3m + 1m at `occurrences` = 2.
At the final entry of `number_of_words` the histogram should reach sum(occurrences).

I do **NOT** want to normalize it.

Comment: Do you want 1 bar, or should be it split to show which parts contribute to the cumsum like in your illustration?

Comment: split into parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split it into parts, plot it twice. The first is the normal cumsum, then second is just the values, with the shifted `cumsum` setting the bottom (This overlaps the top of the previous plotted cumsum).

Using `.iloc[1:]` to slice the Series just before plotting removes the first bar, which you want to exclude.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df['occurrences'].cumsum().iloc[1:].plot(kind='bar', width=1, ec='k', ax=ax)
df['occurrences'].iloc[1:].plot(kind='bar', width=1, ec='k', 
                       bottom=df['occurrences'].cumsum().shift().fillna(0).iloc[1:], ax=ax, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! How can I skip the first bar at 0? ax.set_xlim(1, ) doesn't seem to work

Comment: Thanks, works. Now the lower half of the bar at 1 is red and the upper half blue. Any chances to get rid of red in that first column?

Comment: @Exa see the update, I don't have that issue. Perhaps you had added the `.iloc[1:]` to the wrong spot?

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the update. If I am not mistaken, the updated plot now shows at occurrences = 1 already what should be at occurrences = 2, right? I wanted occurrences = 1 to be approx 2.3m, thus there shouldn't be any red bar.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already got the frequencies worked out, just add it cumulatively:

```
dummy_df['acc'] = dummy_df.occurrences.cumsum()                                                                                                                                                                                       
ax = dummy_df['acc'].plot('bar', width=1, color='b')
dummy_df['acc'].shift().plot('bar', alpha=0.7, width=1, color='r', ax=ax)
```

Comment: FWIW I've added a slightly different approach with both plots.